# Add a counter column to my data frame that increments depending on temperature values (in other column)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new column in my df for the counter that increments when the temperature value goes from ZERO to NON-ZERO.

I am attaching the loop that I using for the logic. the value rests in the counter variable but I want it to be in a column as shown in the table below.

```
prev_temp, counter, n= -300, 0,0

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row.Tempo!=0 and prev_temp==0:
        counter+=1
        n+=1
        prev_temp=rows.Tempo
    elif row.Tempo==0 and prev_temp!= 0:
        prev_temp=rows.Tempo
```

| No. | Tempo | **Count** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 80.0 | 1 |
| 2 | 81.6 | 1 |
| 3 | 0.00 | 1 |
| 4 | 0.00 | 1 |
| 5 | 0.00 | 1 |
| 6 | 81.6 | 2 |
| 7 | 80.0 | 2 |
| 8 | 83.7 | 2 |
| 9 | 0.00 | 2 |
| 10 | 0.00 | 2 |
| 11 | 0.00 | 2 |
| 12 | 81.6 | 3 |

This table here is the expected output!^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a boolean with `shift` & `cumsum` as an incremeting number.

```
s = df['Tempo '].shift().eq(0) & df['Tempo '].gt(0)

df['counter'] = s.cumsum() + 1

  No.   Tempo   Count  counter
0      1    80.0      1        1
1      2    81.6      1        1
2      3     0.0      1        1
3      4     0.0      1        1
4      5     0.0      1        1
5      6    81.6      2        2
6      7    80.0      2        2
7      8    83.7      2        2
8      9     0.0      2        2
9     10     0.0      2        2
10    11     0.0      2        2
11    12    81.6      3        3
```

---

```
print(s)

0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5      True # increment here.
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11     True # increment here.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set all non zero values to 1 and find the difference between sequential elements:

```
df['Count'] =  df.Tempo.gt(0).astype(int).diff().eq(1).cumsum().add(1)
```

Result:

```
    No.  Tempo  Count
0     1   80.0      1
1     2   81.6      1
2     3    0.0      1
3     4    0.0      1
4     5    0.0      1
5     6   81.6      2
6     7   80.0      2
7     8   83.7      2
8     9    0.0      2
9    10    0.0      2
10   11    0.0      2
11   12   81.6      3
```